# How to adjust K-means clustering?

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis

I have tried to leverage [K-means clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) approach for the problem which is formulated similar to the at Wikipedia.

> minimize the within-cluster sum of squares (WCSS):

[image]

but in my formulation **within-cluster sum of modules** has to be minimized.

> set of integers X and number of clusters k are given. Need to choose values of k cluster integers mu such that within-cluster sum of modules of differences is minimized.

I was doing it interatively, picking up initial `mu` values randomly and then adjusting it to the mean of elements assigned to the cluster.

However, this approach gives correct answer only for simple test cases.

Comment: What do you mean by "this approach gives correct answer only for simple test cases"? The K-means approach works as you described: you loop between the two following phases until the centers don't change anymore: 1.You compute the new mu's 2.You assign each element to the closest center.

Comment: What does this question have to do with Java?

Comment: @user1368342, I expect that it minimize not a right utility function. The wiki article states that squares are minimized. My utility function is different.

Comment: It doesn't matter what utility function you use.  The underlying principle described by @user1368342 remains the same.  When you are computing the distance of each point from the cluster centroid, use whatever distance metric you'd like - it doesn't have to be Euclidean distance.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov what's the objective function? Can you give a formula?

Comment: There is another criteria called the "elbow criteria" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determining_the_number_of_clusters_in_a_data_set#The_Elbow_Method

Comment: Or you can use another clustering algorithm that doesn't need K to be specified (like mean shift)

Comment: @RyanJ.Smith, then how to update cluster centroid on each step?

Comment: @Iarsmans, it is same as shown but without `power 2`

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "correct answer"? K-means is strictly depends on initial condition (random selected initial mean centers) and distribution of data. It is not guaranteed that you always get the same mean centers for a distribution.

Comment: Yes, I know that I does not always converge to the optimal solution. So I run it 500/1000 times and select optimal value.